# Is it possible to use DefaultParameterValue in a module?

Tags: .net, f#

In a F# library, I would like to smooth the C# interop. For this I would like to have a default parameter in one my function. To do so, I follow this doc from msdn: [Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters).

In the msdn they used a `type` and yes it works with a type:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Exercise() =
    static let title : string = "Application Development"

    static member Initialize() =
        printfn "%s" "init"
   
    static member Foo([<Optional; DefaultParameterValue("Hello world")>] message) =
        printfn "%s" message

Exercise.Initialize()
Exercise.Foo "tt"
Exercise.Foo () // print "Hello world" Hurray!
```

but when I move to a module, it fail:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module Exercise =
    let title : string = "Application Development"

    let Initialize() =
        printfn "%s" "init"
   
    let Foo([<Optional; DefaultParameterValue("Hello world")>] message: string) =
        printfn "%s" message

Exercise.Initialize()
Exercise.Foo "tt"
Exercise.Foo () // should print "Hello world"
```

I got the error:

> /home/runner/project/Program.fs(15,14): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'string'    but here has type    'unit' [/home/runner/project/project.fsproj]

I can fix the error by replacing the last line by `Exercise.Foo ""`, but this not what I am looking for. I would like to be able to pass `unit` as I did in the `type` snippet.

Is it possible to use DefaultParameterValue in a module? if yes how to do so?

Comment: Optional parameters are only supported for type members, so unfortunately, this will not work.

Comment: If you want to make c#-friendly library you should use classes. Define module with required logic and then create static class that will call functions from it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-net-delegate-types-instead-of-f-function-types